# How to solve error given by eclipse on running runClient?

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am trying to make a basic mod for minecraft and am following a tutorial for the same. When I run runClient, it gives me the following error

```
Reference to undefined variable MC_VERSION
```

Here is my main.java for reference:

```
package rattandeep.basicmod;

import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.Instance;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.SidedProxy;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLPostInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLPreInitializationEvent;
import rattandeep.basicmod.proxy.CommonProxy;
import rattandeep.basicmod.util.Reference;

@Mod(modid = Reference.MOD_ID, name = Reference.NAME, version = Reference.VERSION)
public class Main {
    @Instance
    public static Main instance;
    
    @SidedProxy(clientSide = Reference.CLIENT_PROXY_CLASS, serverSide = Reference.COMMON_PROXY_CLASS)
    public static CommonProxy proxy;
    
    @EventHandler
    public static void PreInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent event) {
        
    }
    
    @EventHandler
    public static void init(FMLInitializationEvent event) {
        
    }

    @EventHandler
    public static void Postinit(FMLPostInitializationEvent event) {
        
    }

}
```

I have searched for a solution but found none. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to solve it. I just needed to change the variable value of MC_VERSION in my runClient launch file to my minecraft version.